# Нужно отслеживать такси на карте

Tags: map, gps, gprs

Допустим нужно отслеживать такси на карте. будет ли хорошим способом установить gprs датчики на каждую машину или есть другие решении?

Comment: Так GPS или GPRS?

Comment: Может gps а не gprs? Как вариант, ставишь датчики, пишеш бекенд, который будет принимать сигналы и сохранять в БД. Далее останется накидать фронт на основе API google.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/162955/

Answer (score 0):

Смартфон водителя и на него Android-приложение.

Но это лучше выдавать водителям смартфоны, т.к. свой собственный в любой момент может выйти из строя, плохо работать и т.п.

Я думал о том, чтобы таких жучков юзать даже при использовании сторонней курьерской службы (в т.ч. пеших курьеров). Выдавать их курьеру вместе с товаром, под росписку о мат. ответственности.